# jQuery if/else hasClass (else not working)

Tags: jquery

I'm trying learn if else statements with jQuery and hasClass. I've done a simple test that won't work and I can't figure out why.

```
if ($('.one').hasClass('left')) {

  $('.button').click(function () {
    $('.one').addClass('right');
    $('.one').removeClass('left');
  })

} else {

  $('.button').click(function () {
    $('.one').addClass('left');
    $('.one').removeClass('right');
  })

}
```

I'm very confused because when I go to the dev tools in Chrome, the first click of the button works fine, and the classes are switched correctly and left is removed. I'm not sure why the else statement won't work though. Everything looks correct to me.

[Link to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0my8h2L1/)

Comment: Do the `if` logic inside of a *single* event handler, and poof, there goes your problem!

Comment: Does registering a new click handler unregister previous ones? If not, both of the handlers are likely firing at once, cancelling each other out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing your check **before** the click, and then the handler always does the same thing.

You want to do your check **in** the handler:

```
$('.button').click(function () {
    if ($('.one').hasClass('left')) {
        $('.one').addClass('right');
        $('.one').removeClass('left');
    } else {
        $('.one').addClass('left');
        $('.one').removeClass('right');
    }
});
```

Or, of course, use [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/), but I took it that you're studying `if/else`...

---

Side note: I wouldn't re-query like that, I'd remember the set and reuse it (along with chaining):

```
$('.button').click(function () {
    var one = $('.one');
    if (one.hasClass('left')) {
        one.addClass('right').removeClass('left');
    } else {
        one.addClass('left').removeClass('right');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is inside out: you should be binding the click event once, and then within the callback function evaluate the if/else condition.

Your current code will only bind one of the two click events, because the `hasClass()` statement is evaluated at runtime.

```js
$(function() {
 $('.button').click(function() {
  if ($('.one').hasClass('left')) {
    $('.one').addClass('right').removeClass('left');
  } else {
    $('.one').addClass('left').removeClass('right');
  }
 });
});
```

```css
.one {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 500ms;
}

.left {
  left: 10px;
}

.right {
  left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one left"></div>
<button class="button">swap</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to put your "if" statement inside the "click" handler:

```
$('.button').click(function () {
  if ($('.one').hasClass('left')) {
    $('.one').addClass('right');
    $('.one').removeClass('left');
  } else {
    $('.one').addClass('left');
    $('.one').removeClass('right');
  }
})
```